# jquery serialize not working in IE9 and IE10

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I use serialize in this code, works fine in IE 8 and chrome but the post data is not comming back in IE 9 and IE 10. Looks that the PHP code is not executed properly, but than it also cant work in IE 8. So it has to be a Jquery problem (i supose).

```
$(document).on("submit",     "#basis_advertentie,#prijzen_huidige_jaar,#basisgegevens_verhuur,#plaatsen_advertentie_stap3", function(event) {
        //Tinymce heeft dit nodig voor de POST data
        if (this.id == 'basis_advertentie'){tinyMCE.get("omschrijving_wijzigen").save();}
        var innertab = "#innertab_"+this.id;
        /* stop form from submitting normally */
        event.preventDefault();      
        if (this.name != 'plaatsen_advertentie_stap3'){
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:this.id+".php",
                cache: false,                   
                data: $("#"+this.id).serialize(),
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
                    wijziging_nog_bevestigen = 0;
                    $(innertab).html(data);
                }       
            });
        }            else {
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"../plaatsen_advertentie/plaatsen_advertentie_stap3.php",
                cache: false,                   
                data: $("#plaatsen_advertentie_stap3").serialize(),
                success:function(data){
                    wijziging_nog_bevestigen = 0;
                    $("#tab_2").html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: I doubt this is a jQuery or Internet Explorer issue. Try checking your Console (via F12) for messages.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it! There was a '/n' in my select options list, removed it and the problem was gone! Strange but thrue...